# trigger function

Tags: postgresql

how to create trigger functions? where it called? in PostgreSQL..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html) yet? It contains a [complete example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-example.html) as well.